# Ant jmeter task is not executed without -v option

Tags: ant, build, jmeter, task

I have the following strange situation - the jmeter test is not executed, if i didn't specified "-v" option. 
Here is an example

> C:\jmeter>ant run Buildfile: C:\jmeter\build.xml
>
> clean:    [delete] Deleting directory C:\jmeter\result    [delete]
>   Deleting directory C:\jmeter\log
>
> show-test-properties:
>        [echo] JMETER_HOME                         : C:\temp\apache-jmeter-2.13
>        [echo] TEST_PATH                           : C:\jmeter/test
>        [echo] TEST_NAME                           : tag.jmx
>        [echo] THREADGROUP_COUNT                   : 2
>        [echo] THREADGROUP_RAMPUP                  : 2
>        [echo] THREADGROUP_DURATION                : 60
>
> run:
>       [mkdir] Created dir: C:\jmeter\result
>       [mkdir] Created dir: C:\jmeter\log    [jmeter] Executing test plan: C:\jmeter\test\tag.jmx ==> C:\jmeter\result\result.jtl

But test is not executed at all.
And now with -v ( which is only verbose and shouldn't affect the run itself"):

> [jmeter] Executing 'C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\jre\bin\java.exe' with arguments:    [jmeter]
>   '-Xmx5120m'    [jmeter] '-jar'    [jmeter]
>   'C:\jmeter-2.13\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar'    [jmeter] '-n'    [jmeter]
>   '-j'    [jmeter] 'C:\jmeter\log\jmeter.log'    [jmeter] '-t'
>   [jmeter] 'C:\jmeter\test\tag.jmx'    [jmeter] '-l'    [jmeter]
>   'C:\jmeter\result\result.jtl'    [jmeter]
>   '-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml'    [jmeter]
>   '-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=all'    [jmeter]
>   '-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true'    [jmeter]
>   '-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true'    [jmeter]
>   '-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true'    [jmeter]
>   '-Jthreadgroup.count=2'    [jmeter] '-Jthreadgroup.rampup=2'
>   [jmeter] '-Jthreadgroup.duration=60'    [jmeter]    [jmeter] The '
>   characters around the executable and arguments are    [jmeter] not
>   part of the command.    [jmeter] Creating summariser 
>   [jmeter] Created the tree successfully using C:\jmeter\test\tag.jmx
>
> [jmeter] Starting the test @ Mon Feb 29 10:25:57 CET 2016
>   (1456737957623)    [jmeter] Waiting for possible shutdown message on
>   port 4445    [jmeter] summary =     20 in   1.4s =   13.8/s Avg:   198
>   Min:    60 Max:   4 26 Err:    10 (50.00%)    [jmeter] Tidying up ... 
>   @ Mon Feb 29 10:25:59 CET 2016 (1456737959184)    [jmeter] ... end of
>   run
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 3 seconds

Any ideas, helps, hints?

Comment: What is the error you see?  Err: 10 (50.00%). Any useful info in the log?
Your Ant/java versions?

Comment: The error 50% is , because I am using dummy sample 50:50 (success: failed). I am using the latest versions of ant and jdk. It is very, very weird actually I have never observed such behavior until now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with your `Ant`.

Check the ant version. It should be 1.9.6.

[image]

There was an issue with Ant 1.9.5 + Java >1.8  & it got fixed in Ant 1.9.6

Comment: I am using ant version 1.9.6 and java "1.8.0_74".
It is quite odd, since build is successful, but without any actual tests and results. 
In the build.xml there is nothing, that could cause such behavior..

Comment: I have changed my java version to the latest available jdk1.7.0_79 and now everything works as expected. 

So probably the fix applied for 1.9.6 for jdk 1.8 is not working properly.

Thanks, Vinoth